# Creating a different php configuration of a subdomain

Tags: php

I have mysite.com and sub.mysite.com

php.ini is set to display_errors=off

but for sub.mysite.com which is a testing site, I want display_errors=on

how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

Add this to the .htaccess file in the root of the subdomain

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to your specific php.ini setup.
You may be able to, depending upon your configuration, to inject into the .htaccess and/or into a local site php.ini file the settings you want to show.

If your using cPanel (may work with others as well) try the following:

```
# cp -pv /usr/local/lib/php.ini /home/username/public_html/php.ini
# chown -v username:username /home/username/public_html/php.ini
```

Keep in mind if safe mode is enabled - than this will not work. 
PHP link:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: I don't have cPanel